# Is there a formal grammar for english language?

Tags: parsing, nlp

I'm browsing web searching for english language grammar, but i found only few simple examples like:

```
s -> np vp
np -> det n
vp -> v | v np
det -> 'a' | 'the'
n -> 'woman' | 'man'
v -> 'shoots'
```

Maybe I don't realise how big this problem is because i tought that grammar has been formalised. Can somebody provide me a source for some expanded formal english grammar?

Comment: A complete grammar considering all possible words probably does not exist. However, it would in any case make more sense to have a generic linguistic model on a more syntactical level.

Comment: Yes, there is a formal grammar for English, but there's a big problem: It's ambiguous. The same sentence could mean different things depending on how you parse it. Someone who speaks English chooses the correct interpretation based on context.

Comment: Think of puns. They work by using ambiguities.

Comment: Better answers to this question can be found at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32447/is-there-an-ebnf-that-covers-all-of-english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to examine the work of Noam Chomsky and the people that followed him. I believe much of his work was on the generative properties of language. See the [Generative Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_grammar) article on Wikipedia for more details.

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer his question, but I heartily agree that he should read up on Chomsky, so +1.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [English Resource Grammar](http://www.delph-in.net/erg/), which you can use with the LKB or [PET](http://wiki.delph-in.net/moin/PetTop)

Answer (score 6):

Not perfect, surely not complete, not ideal from the theoretical point of view. But the nicest one I found: http://www.scientificpsychic.com/grammar/enggram1.html

Answer (score 5):

It would be huge. Probably not possible.

Human languages are interpreted by "analog" creatures in (generally) a very forgiving way, not by dumb digital machines that can insist that rules be followed. They do tend to have some kind of underlying structure, but exceptions abound. Really the only "rule" is to make it possible for others to understand you.

Even among biological languages, English would be about the worst possible choice, because of its history. It started probably as a pidgen of various different Germanic languages (with attendent simplifications), then had a large amount of French overlaid onto it after the Norman Conquest, then had bits and peices of nearly every language in the world grafted onto it.

To give you some idea of the scale we are talking about, let's assume we can consider dictionaries to be your list of terminals for a human language. The only major work that makes a passable stab at being comprehensive for English is the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary), which contains more than **half a million** entries. However, very few people probably know more than 1/10th of them. That means that if you picked out random words from the OED and built sentences out of them, most English speakers would have trouble even recognizing the result as English.

Different groups of speakers tend to know different sets of words too. So just about every user of the language learns to tailor their vocabulary (list of used terminals) to their audience. I speak very differently to my buddies from the "wrong side of the tracks" than I do with my family, and different still than I do here on SO.

Comment: This answer seems to be confusing syntax with semantics.  Knowledge of word meanings gives you 1) enhanced ability to resolve ambiguity, and 2) the ability to exclude non-sensical sentences from the language (colorless green ideas sleep furiously).  Neither of these are necessary for specifying a comprehensive grammar that excludes invalid sentences.

Comment: @SigmaX - Your list of terminals (your lexemes) are an inherent part of the grammar. For example, consider the sentences "Jesus wept." and "Run away!" There's no way of knowing that the first is `Noun` `Verb` and the second is `verb` `adverb` without knowing the definitions of those words.

Comment: ...and we won't even get into the fact that in most contexts `verb` `adverb` sentences are supposed to be illegal in English, and this is a special case (called "imperative", and weaseled out of by introducing the concept of an implied subject that isn't allowed in most contexts). I'm trying to avoid explaining all that mess simply by showing that the most basic step, coming up with an exhaustive and consistent list of terminals, can't really be done anyway.

Comment: Probably the real person to consult on this subject beyond Chomsky is [Goedel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del's_incompleteness_theorems). Computer languages tend to get around the incompleteness problem by compromising on completeness. There may be some useful things that are difficult to express in them, but they are fairly consistent so you can create nice grammars for them. Human languages go the other way and compromise on consistency. That's no biggie for humans as we'd much rather be able to write and understand great poetry than be understood 100% correctly all the time

Comment: @SigmaX - I'm not entirely sure your example is even "non-sensical". In the right context (with the right surrounding sentences or the right shared knowledge between the writer and the reader) "colorless green ideas" could easily be a metaphor for something. After all, "green" can mean "inexperienced", and "colorless" can mean "boring", and "sleep" has oodles of metaphorical meanings. I've read passages of Joyce that make far less sense (to me).

Comment: All good points, except that your your Gödel reference makes me raise an eyebrow.  Incompleteness has nothing to do with how "easy" or "hard" something is to express.  All full computer languages are Turing-complete, so they do not "compromise" on anything, computationally speaking.  Also, when you say human languages sacrifice "consistency," aren't you referring to a different kind of "consistency" than we mean in axiomatic systems?  Like, syntactic consistency vs. logical consistency, or some such thing?

Comment: Chomsky's theory that spawned formal languages and automata discipline in Computer Science was created by studying human languages. It is widely believed by linguistics that natural languages follow a context-sensitive grammar, while computer languages try to stay context-free, although they don't always succeed (see C++). That said, no one will include every word in a formal grammar, but since every word always fit a syntactic role (verb, noun, etc) it is indeed possible to model any human language as a formal grammar. That is why Chomsky is regarded as a linguist, not a mathematician.

Answer (score 4):

Look at Attempto Controlled English : http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/site/

Answer (score 0):

The standard non-electronic resource is [The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/).